# How to set up a custom HTTP error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to create a custom 403 error page.
Currently I already have an Ingress created and in the annotations I have something like this:

```
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "100.01.128.0/20,88.100.01.01"
```

So any attempt to access my web app outside that IP range receives a 403 error.

In order to create a custom page I tried adding the following annotations:

```
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors": "403",
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend": "default-http-backend"
```

where default-http-backend is the name of an app already deployed.
[image: Pod details]

the ingress has this:

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "my-app-ingress",
    "namespace": "my-app-test",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/my-app-test/ingresses/my-app-ingress",
    "uid": "8f31f2b4-428d-11ea-b15a-ee0dcf00d5a8",
    "resourceVersion": "129105581",
    "generation": 3,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-01-29T11:50:34Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors": "403",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend": "default-http-backend",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "100.01.128.0/20,90.108.01.012"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "tls": [
      {
        "hosts": [
          "my-app-test.retail-azure.js-devops.co.uk"
        ],
        "secretName": "ssl-secret"
      }
    ],
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "my-app-test.retail-azure.js-devops.co.uk",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/api",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "my-app-backend",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            },
            {
              "path": "/",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "my-app-frontend",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Yet I always get the default 403.
What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried your config here and everything was fine to me. Your services "my-app-frontend", "default-http-backend" and the ingress are in the same namespace?

Comment: they all are in the same front end, but i dont see the "default-http-backend" when accessing my web app from a non white listed IP...(I still see the real default one). I have no ideia how it works for you or why...  it might be because i acutally used "default-http-backend" as the service name... that might be a conflict

Comment: can you describe the service default-http-backend? Also can you provide ips of the pods that you want as default backend?

Answer (score 11):

I've reproduced your scenario and that worked for me.
I will try to guide you in steps I've followed.

**Cloud provider**: GKE
**Kubernetes Version**: v1.15.3
**Namespace**: `default`

I'm using 2 deployments of 2 images with a service for each one.

**Service 1**: `default-http-backend` - with nginx image, it will be our default backend.

**Service 2**: `custom-http-backend` - with inanimate/echo-server image, this service will be displayed if the request become from a whitelisted ip.

**Ingress**: Nginx ingress with annotations.

**Expected behavior:** The ingress will be configured to use [default-backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#default-backend), [custom-http-errors](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-http-errors) and [whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) annotations. If the request was made from a whitelisted ip the ingress will redirect to **custom-http-backend**, if not it will be redirect to **default-http-backend**.

#### Deployment 1: default-http-backend

Create a file `default-http-backend.yaml` with this content:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: default-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Apply the yaml file: `k apply -f default-http-backend.yaml`

#### Deployment 2: custom-http-backend

Create a file `custom-http-backend.yaml` with this content:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: custom-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: custom-http-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: custom-http-backend
        image: inanimate/echo-server
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: custom-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Apply the yaml file: `k apply -f custom-http-backend.yaml`

#### Check if services is up and running

*I'm using the alias `k` for `kubectl`*

```
➜  ~ k get svc                                 
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
custom-http-backend    ClusterIP   10.125.5.227   <none>        80/TCP    73s
default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.125.9.218   <none>        80/TCP    5m41s
...
```

```
➜  ~ k get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
custom-http-backend-67844fb65d-k2mwl    1/1     Running   0          2m10s
default-http-backend-5485f569bd-fkd6f   1/1     Running   0          6m39s
...
```

You could test the service using [port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/):

**default-http-backend**
`k port-forward svc/default-http-backend 8080:80`
Try to access http://localhost:8080 in your browse to see the nginx default page.

**custom-http-backend**
`k port-forward svc/custom-http-backend 8080:80`
Try to access http://localhost:8080 in your browse to see the custom page provided by the echo-server image.

#### Ingress configuration

At this point we have both services up and running, we need to install and configure the nginx ingress. You can follow the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), this will not covered here.

After installed let's deploy the ingress, based in the code you posted i did some modifications: tls removed, added other domain and removed the path `/api` for tests purposes only and add my home ip to whitelist.

Create a file `my-app-ingress.yaml` with the content:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '403'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: default-http-backend
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 207.34.xxx.xx/32
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.rabello.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: custom-http-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Apply the spec: `k apply -f my-app-ingress.yaml`

Check the ingress with the command:

```
➜  ~ k get ing
NAME             HOSTS              ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
my-app-ingress   myapp.rabello.me   146.148.xx.xxx   80      36m
```

**That's all!**

If I test from home with my whitelisted ip, the custom page is showed, but if i try to access using my cellphone in 4G network, the nginx default page is displayed.

Note I'm using ingress and services in the same namespace, if you need work with different namespace you need to use [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname).

I hope that helps!

**References:**
[kubernetes deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

[kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

[nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

[nginx annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)

Comment: I've let this go for a while. havent had the time to double check but i might have an old version of nginx and this might be my problem https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4576

Answer (score 1):

I want to create a custom 403 error page. Currently I already have an Ingress created and in the annotations.
So any attempt to access my web app outside that IP range receives a 403 error.
In order to create a custom page I tried adding the following annotations:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: '403'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: default-http-backend
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 125.10.156.36/32
spec:
  rules:
  - host: venkat.dev.vboffice.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: custom-http-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

where default-http-backend is the name of an app already deployed with default nginx page.

If I test from home with my whitelisted ip, the custom page is showed, but if i try to access using my cellphone in 4G network, it will display default backend 404

i need to add any nginx config change custom-http-backend pod????

Deployment 1:default-http-backend

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: default-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Deployment 2: custom-http-backend

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: custom-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: custom-http-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: custom-http-backend
        image: inanimate/echo-server
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: custom-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

One can customize the 403 error page for `ingress-nginx` (/etc/nginx/template), just by editing the `nginx.tmpl` file. Then mounting it to ingress nginx controller deployment.Below is the part of the `nginx.tmpl` need to be edited:

```
{{/* Build server redirects (from/to www) */}}
    {{ range $redirect := .RedirectServers }}
    ## start server {{ $redirect.From }}
    server {
        server_name {{ $redirect.From }};

        {{ buildHTTPListener  $all $redirect.From }}
        {{ buildHTTPSListener $all $redirect.From }}

        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            certificate.call()
        }
        error_page 403 /403.html;
        {{ if gt (len $cfg.BlockUserAgents) 0 }}
        if ($block_ua) {
          return 403;
        }
        {{ end }}
        {{ if gt (len $cfg.BlockReferers) 0 }}
        if ($block_ref) {
          return 403;
        }
        {{ end }}
        location = /403.html {
          root /usr/local/nginx/html/;
          internal;
        }

        set_by_lua_block $redirect_to {
            local request_uri = ngx.var.request_uri
            if string.sub(request_uri, -1) == "/" then
                request_uri = string.sub(request_uri, 1, -2)
            end

            {{ if ne $all.ListenPorts.HTTPS 443 }}
            {{ $redirect_port := (printf ":%v" $all.ListenPorts.HTTPS) }}
            return string.format("%s://%s%s%s", ngx.var.scheme, "{{ $redirect.To }}", "{{ $redirect_port }}", request_uri)
            {{ else }}
            return string.format("%s://%s%s", ngx.var.scheme, "{{ $redirect.To }}", request_uri)
            {{ end }}
        }

        return {{ $all.Cfg.HTTPRedirectCode }} $redirect_to;
    }
    ## end server {{ $redirect.From }}
    {{ end }}

    {{ range $server := $servers }}

    ## start server {{ $server.Hostname }}
    server {
        server_name {{ buildServerName $server.Hostname }} {{range $server.Aliases }}{{ . }} {{ end }};

        error_page 403 /403.html;
        {{ if gt (len $cfg.BlockUserAgents) 0 }}
        if ($block_ua) {
          return 403;
        }
        {{ end }}
        {{ if gt (len $cfg.BlockReferers) 0 }}
        if ($block_ref) {
          return 403;
        }
        {{ end }}
        location = /403.html {
          root /usr/local/nginx/html/;
          internal;
        }

        {{ template "SERVER" serverConfig $all $server }}

        {{ if not (empty $cfg.ServerSnippet) }}
        # Custom code snippet configured in the configuration configmap
        {{ $cfg.ServerSnippet }}
        {{ end }}

        {{ template "CUSTOM_ERRORS" (buildCustomErrorDeps "upstream-default-backend" $cfg.CustomHTTPErrors $all.EnableMetrics) }}
    }
    ## end server {{ $server.Hostname }}

    {{ end }}
```

In the above snippet `error_apge 403 /403.html;` is declared before we return `403`. Then the location of `/403.html` is defined. The root path is same where one should mount the `403.html` page. In this case its `/usr/local/nginx/html/`.
Below snippet will help you mount the volume with custom pages.

```
volumes:
- name: custom-errors
  configMap:
    # Provide the name of the ConfigMap you want to mount.
    name: custom-ingress-pages
    items:
    - key: "404.html"
      path: "404.html"
    - key: "403.html"
      path: "403.html"
    - key: "50x.html"
      path: "50x.html"
    - key: "index.html"
      path: "index.html"
```

This solution doesn't require you to spawn another/extra service or pod of any kind to work.

For more info: https://engineering.zenduty.com/blog/2022/03/02/customizing-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and deploy custom default backend which will return a custom error page.Follow the [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/) to deploy a custom default backend and configure nginx ingress controller by modifying the deployment yaml to use this custom default backend.

The deployment yaml for the custom default backend is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/34b6d083b86c5ea367aa69ec292db3ed55e98b53/docs/examples/customization/custom-errors/custom-default-backend.yaml) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/images/custom-error-pages).