# Redirect mlflow 404 to custom error page URI instead of returning "The requested URL was not found on the server" error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, mlflow

I am deploying MLflow on a Kubernetes cluster and using NGINX Ingress Controller as reverse proxy and load balancer.

I would like to customise the MLflow ingress, so that accessing a link that doesn't exist will return a custom error page instead of "Not Found" &
"The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Currently, a couple of custom error pages are hosted on a separate deployment and would like to redirect to those pages instead.

The nginx ingress controlller default backend looked appropriate however I'd prefer a URI redirect to introducing another component and hosting the custom error pages there.

Here is an ingress example:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mlflow-ingress
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mlflow
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 150m
    layer.quantumblack.com/description: "Log your experiments and metrics"
    layer.quantumblack.com/name: "MLFlow"
    layer.quantumblack.com/service_type: "mlflow"
    layer.quantumblack.com/url: "https://example.com/mlflow/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: "404, 500, 502, 503, 504"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      error_page 404 502 "https://example.com/404";
      error_page 403 "https://example.com/403";
```

With this setup, going to https://example.com/mlflow/#/experiments/0 will redirect to the custom error page but going to https://example.com/mlflow/1234 will return the aforementioned error.

I tried the example above and it redirects as long the server has problems (e.g. nginx 404 not found or 502 bad gateway) but doesn't satisfy the use case mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Nginx [Custom Errors](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/#custom-errors).

I'll share you some links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205943/21404450

https://www.callumpember.com/Easy-Kubernetes-Nginx-Ingress-Custom-Error-Pages/